# Yii2 - Passing a value to the Where Clause in Dropdownlist

Tags: yii2

I have two models:

**QuestionCategories**

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'question_category_id' => 'ID',
        'course_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Course'),
        'name' => Yii::t('course', 'Question Category Name'),
        'is_status' => Yii::t('course', 'Is Status'),
    ];
}
```

**Questions**

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'question_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Question ID'),
        'question_category_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Question Category'),
        'question_course_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Course'),
        'instructor_id' => Yii::t('course', 'Instructor'),
        'question_name' => Yii::t('course', 'Question Name'),
    ];
}
```

In the View of **Questions**, I want to create a Dropdownlist where the course_id in **QuestionCategories** is equal to the question_course_id in the **Questions.**

How do I achieve this?

See what I have done so far.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'question_category_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(QuestionCategories::find()->all(),'question_category_id','name'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Question Category ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used getRequest() to resolve the issue. This enable me to obtain the parameter.

```
<?php $courseid = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('acs_id');?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'question_category_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(QuestionCategories::find()->where(['course_id' => $courseid, 'is_status'=>0])->all(),'question_category_id','name'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Question Category ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
?>
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

`question_course_id` has to be  pre-determined before you can add that to your condition:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'question_category_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(QuestionCategories::find()->where(['course_id' => $your_Course_id])->all(),'question_category_id','name'),
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Question Category ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
    'allowClear' => true
    ],
]);
?>
```

Please refer to [Yii 2 Guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record%20%22Yii2%20Doc) - Query Builder & Active record.

Comment: `//The parameter is $acs_id. How do I pass it from the Controller to the Dropdownlist in the View
    public function actionCreate($acs_id)
    {        
        $model = new Questions();        

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->question_id]);
        } else
            {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }`

Comment: how is `$acs_id` determined? ie: is it selected by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the answer by Kalu and your comment, I think the Yii way to do it would be to pass the parameter to your view via Controller, like so:

```
//The parameter is $acs_id. How do I pass it from the Controller to the Dropdownlist in the View 
public function actionCreate($acs_id) { 
   $model = new Questions(); 
   if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) { 
       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->question_id]); } 
   else { return $this->render('create', [ 'model' => $model, 'acs_id' => $acs_id]); }
```

In that way you would be able to access $acs_id as a variable in the view without accessing the request directly.